# How can I export a shapefile from PostGIS with a GeoJSON query?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, gdal, geojson, pgsql2shp

I tried to export a shapefile from my PostGIS installation using pgsql2shp as follow

```
pgsql2shp -f tiles.shp -h <host> -u <user> -P <pass> <database> "SELECT id, the_geom FROM <table> WHERE ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -92.472398018272358, 18.086381878379395 ], [ -92.472398018272358, 21.705890714546868 ], [ -86.679183238981381, 21.705890714546868 ], [ -86.679183238981381, 18.086381878379395 ], [ -92.472398018272358, 18.086381878379395 ] ] ] }') && the_geom;"
```

and the command gives the error

```
Error executing user query: ERROR:  quoted object property name expected (at offset 2)
```

I suppose is a problem related with the GeoJSON query because when I run

```
pgsql2shp -f tiles.shp -h <host> -u <user> -P <pass> <database> "SELECT id, the_geom FROM <table> WHERE id = 1;"
```

the shapefile is generated without error.

Comment: this might be an issue with escaping of quotes and apostrophes in your json query. have you tried escaping them with a preceding backslash (\\)? You might want to [check this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55210/pgsql2shp-error-when-query-is-introduced) too.

Comment: @StevenKay You are totally right. It's just a problem with quotes on the geojson, it resolved when quotes are escaped, just quotes, apostrophes are not necessary

Answer (score 1):

As @StevenKay mentioned, quotes on the GeoJSON should be escaped with preceding backslash.

```
pgsql2shp -f tiles.shp -h <host> -u <user> -P <pass> <database> "SELECT id, the_geom FROM <table> WHERE ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ \"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [ [ [ -92.472398018272358, 18.086381878379395 ], [ -92.472398018272358, 21.705890714546868 ], [ -86.679183238981381, 21.705890714546868 ], [ -86.679183238981381, 18.086381878379395 ], [ -92.472398018272358, 18.086381878379395 ] ] ] }') && the_geom;"
```

Another solution are presented on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55210/pgsql2shp-error-when-query-is-introduced).

Comment: great! It would be nice if pgsql2shp allowed queries from files or stdin.. If you do this a lot, it might be worth writing a short python script to do the escaping and calling it via os.system()